# Problem looping through web controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a web page where I am dynamically creating controls during `Page_Load` event (this is done so because I do not know how many controls I will need until session is active and certain variables are accessible)

I need to be able to loop through these controls to find Checkbox when a button click is processed. Looping through the Form.Controls does not appear to be sufficient. I would think that `Request.Form` might work but it does not appear to be accessible in my C# block?

What should code for `Request.Form` look like? OR

Has anyone done this before with dynamically created controls?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: If you can avoid creating control, that would be easier. I personnaly prefer using a repeater to "create" controls. Your problem prolly comes from the fact that your control are not recreated before you try looping through ... Dynamically created control need to be recreated on each postback.

Comment: What does your C# block look like? Where does it sit? Can you post some of it?

Comment: Thanks for the insight guys. I kind of took the discussion and ran with it and found my solution that worked best for me.

    foreach(String chk in Request.Form)
            {
                if (chk.Contains("chkRemove"))
                {
                    int idxFormat = chk.LastIndexOf("chkRemove");
                    objectname = chk.Substring(idxFormat);


Turned out really all I needed was the name. The string contained a number at the end which was needed to determine a position of datatable items.

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Wow that code did not format...sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the insight guys. I kind of took the discussion and ran with it and found my solution that worked best for me.

```
foreach(String chk in Request.Form) 
{
    if (chk.Contains("chkRemove")) 
    {
        int idxFormat = chk.LastIndexOf("chkRemove"); 
        objectname = chk.Substring(idxFormat);
    }
}
```

Turned out really all I needed was the name. The string contained a number at the end which was needed to determine a position of datatable items. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

Simplified Example from MSDN:

```
var myControl = FindControl("NameOfControl");
if(myControl != null)
{
   //do something
}
else
{
   //control not found
}
```

Hope this helps! ;)

Comment: This is not applicable to controls created in a Page_Load event since it is not included in the ViewState. You would find a control but the control would not be the same control and its state would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Your controls will be accessible trough the `Controls` collection of their immediate parent. Unless you add them like `Page.Form.Controls.Add (myControl);`, you won't find it in `Page.Form.Conttrols`. If you add them to a place holder, you must find them in `thePlaceHolder.Controls`.

```
LinkButton myDynamicLinkButton = new myDynamicLinkButton ();
myDynamicLinkButton.ID = "lnkButton";

myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add (myDynamicLinkButton);

//........

LinkButton otherReferenceToMyLinkButton = myPlaceHolder.FindControl ("lnkButton");
```

As @David said in his comment, you should probably think about using a Repeater instead. It would probably simplify your case a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Since the controls might be nested in other controls, you need to search recursively. You can use this method to find the control:

```
 public Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
 {
     if (root.ID == id)
     {
         return root;
     }

     foreach (Control c in root.Controls)
     {
         Control t = FindControlRecursive(c, id);
         if (t != null)
         {
             return t;
         }
     }

     return null;
 }
```

And you can implement it this way:

```
CheckBox check = FindControlRecursive(Page.Form, "CheckBox1");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have access to `Request["xyz"]` anywhere in your aspx.cs code. You can either find control as described above and read it's value or do so directly from Request using the `Control.UniqueID` property. For example if it's a checkbox that's within the repeater then the `UniqueID` would look like dtgData$ctl02$txtAmount